# JQuery add attribute to anchor tag in specific div tag with id pattern content class

Tags: jquery, html

can anyone please tell me how to add attribute target=_blank to a anchor tag in div class content. it seems simple, but I could not get it worked, I'm getting the content in div i required, but unable to add attribute to it.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<div id="row-url_1" class="crm-section url_1-section">
            <div class="label">
                Website
            </div>
             <div class="content">
                <a href="http://www.wesite.com">http://www.website.com ( Home ) </a>
             </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
```

you can find the demo at
http://jsfiddle.net/Lred3to2/

Many Thanks

Comment: `<a href="http://www.wesite.com" target="_blank">http://www.website.com ( Home ) </a>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/27jvqnag/ using jquery `$('.content a').prop('target', '_blank')`

Comment: I need that attribute for anchor tag to open in new window. not the value of anchor tag

Comment: @Satpal in my context i'm unable to reach to anchor tag, can you please use it in my fiddle pls. I got several other div tags, which dont need to be opened in new window, only to this div block i need to add attribute. you can see my selector cj("div[id*='row-url']")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use

```
$('.content a').prop('target', '_blank')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/27jvqnag/)

As per your code use

```
cj("div[id*='row-url']").find('.content a').prop('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: tried your code but, getting error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( ... it seems its not accepting ("a") after this: children('.content')

Comment: @Developer, In which line? USe `cj("div[id*='row-url']").find('.content a').prop('target', '_blank')`

Comment: great friend. thanks alot. its working fine now with following ur code cj("div[id*='row-url']").find('.content a').prop('target', '_blank');